# Search within a column and another collection

Tags: xamarin.android

Use this code to search within two columns. The code works great.
The need has changed. Now I want to search (SubHeading) andalso sum (Heading) another column

column TYPE = SubHeading = search, column = PRICE = Heading

The tool I use is listview.
The data is as follows

TYPE  ,  PRICE  , COUNT ,  TOT

ORANGE  , 10  ,    5   ,    50

```
if (_adapter._originalData != null && _adapter._originalData.Any())
                {

                    results.AddRange(
                        _adapter._originalData.Where(
                            item => item.SubHeading.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString()) | item.Heading.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString())));

                }
```

Comment: Can you provide your data structure and related view? According to your description, I even cannot reproduce your issue or running view. You used listview heading or Gridview?

Comment: HI  , I use listview

Comment: Do you want to achieve the result like the filter function? After filter it, listview will be refreshed(just display the filtered data).